# Can get IP after upgrading to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, networking

Had upgraded my laptop from 11.04 to 11.10, desktop ubuntu. And made fresh install of ubuntu server 11.10 on another comp.

And now a have exactly same problem on **both** computers:

It doesn't have working network after boot. `ifconfig -a` is saying that there is no IP address. Unplugging/plugging ethernet cable doesn't work. I have to make `sudo dhclient -4 eth0` by myself to make it working, every time after boot. It helps, but it's annoying.

wtf? how to fix that?

PS everything worked fine on same network, just before upgrading to 11.10. Other devices still working on this network without any problem.

---

Update 1:

Had fixed this problem on laptop, there was no any configuration to ethernet network, at network-manager (and i'm sure that it was there, before upgrade). Just made new one, and configured it as 'auto-connect'. Seems that is working now.

btw, other my comp, didn't have 'Network Manager' and event graphical interface.

---

Update 2:

When i'm making `sudo dhclient eth1` I get following in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Oct 17 12:02:51 towerserv kernel: [  482.693427] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
Oct 17 12:02:51 towerserv dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Oct 17 12:02:53 towerserv kernel: [  484.561428] sky2 0000:03:00.0: eth1: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex, flow control both
Oct 17 12:02:53 towerserv kernel: [  484.561571] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
Oct 17 12:02:54 towerserv dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
Oct 17 12:02:55 towerserv dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.105 from 192.168.1.1
Oct 17 12:02:55 towerserv dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.105 on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Oct 17 12:02:55 towerserv dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.105 from 192.168.1.1
Oct 17 12:02:55 towerserv dhclient: bound to 192.168.1.105 -- renewal in 40855 seconds.
Oct 17 12:03:04 towerserv kernel: [  495.376004] eth1: no IPv6 routers present
```

---

Update 3

**Fixed** by adding following lines into `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 1):

In hope of getting interesting log messages:

Turn of network,
wait 2 seconds,
turn on network.

This should be situation where you don't have IP (check it please).

Post relevant sections of `dmesg` and /var/log/syslog.

Get ip with `sudo dhclient -4 eth0`.

Post updates to `dmesg` and syslog.

Comment: Hi! Make an update, have added `/var/log/syslog` after executing 'sudo dhclient eth1'. Btw, i'm not sure what sections of dmesg are relevant to this issue, and what i need to attach to my question. Can you suggest, please?

Comment: Hi. From what I understand, you managed to fix the problem on your own (lack of network configuration)?

Comment: yes, i've fixed it on one of my computers. Still have it in another one :(

Comment: What happens when you restart network? Does it still not work?

Comment: Has fixed it by editing /etc/network/interfaces, see Update 4. Thanks